# Get a variable from an anonymous class

Tags: java

I have the following situation :

```
final String value = null;
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {                
            value = response;
        }
    });     
    System.out.println(value);
```

I am running this code from my main class.

Now I need to be able to use the variable (String Response) from the over ridden class in my main class.

How am i meant to go about getting this variable, as clearly what i have doesnt work.

ps, suggest an edit for the name, I didnt know what to call it.

Comment: The whole point of an Async method is that you cannot use it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't have to do with classes; it's that you're using asynchronous code synchronously. Anything you want to do with the string response must be within the `onSuccess` handler (or a function called by it).

Comment: So how would I get it back to my main class then?

I need to display say for eg. a list in my main class, which my async class gets fro me. but I need it to return the actual list? I am assuming I need some sort of design pattern or technique to get it?

Comment: @Zapnologica You have to rethink your design. If you need to display it right away, use a synchronous http client.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do need to display it right away, but 1: The network request takes some time to get the data, so its not exactly right away, and 2: With android you sholdnt run such types of methods on the main activity as it can cause the app to become unresponsive. So how would I have to rethink my design? What do I need to do?  Can I not make a method, displaydata(string data) in the main class and then on the async class onsuccess I call that method?

Comment: @Zapnologica Do you know about the `Observer` pattern? In your `onSuccess` method, you could notify some listener (maybe one that has a reference a text field) that the value is ready and therefore update its state (update the text field). But you cannot sysout the value right away because it simply isn't available.

Comment: is this an appropriate implementation of the observer pattern that I need to implement? http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

Comment: @Rosarch , I have been thinking, What i really need is for a function that updates the android user interface, that I can put in my while loop on the main activity. Then my main activity will remain reactive while waiting for the response. I know there is a function in C# which does it. called: `Application.DoEvents();`